# Is there a way to Set ttl in elastic search index

Tags: elasticsearch

I can  see that docs say that we can set `ttl` on a document but not on index/indices. Also wanted to know if it has any performance impact if we set `ttl`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`_ttl` is [enabled per index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-ttl-field.html#mapping-ttl-field), but the expiration works per document.

If you want your indices to "expire", delete them. Much more simple and performant.

And yes, `_ttl` has a performance impact.
The Elasticsearch "way" of dealing with "expired" data is to create time-based indices. Meaning, for each day or each week you create an index. Index everything belonging to that day/week in that index. You decide how many days you want to keep around and stick to that number.

Let's say that you want to keep the data for 7 days. In the 8th day you create the new index, as usual, then you delete the index from 8 days before. All the time you'll have in your cluster 7 indices. The `ttl` mechanism checks every `indices.ttl.interval` (60 seconds by default) for expired documents, it creates bulk requests out of them and deletes them. This means unnecessary requests coming to the cluster.

Instead, deleting an index is very easy and quick.

Take a look at [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/time-based.html) and how to easily manage time based indices with [Curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html).

Comment: Bummer actually it would  be easier to have TTL per document, like cassandra has in this case.  Performance isn't an issue

Thank you!

Comment: expiration per document solution/approach is deprecated now. Index Lifetime Policies are encouraged to use in newer Elastic versions 7+ instead

Answer (score 7):

`_ttl`-like approach is deprecated now (cause of performance impact of reiteration over and over) and Elastic introduced [index lifecycle management (ILM)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html)

So what you would like to do instead now is a dynamic index creation each day for instance with a date-specific name pattern e.g. `my-app-log-yyyy-mm-dd` and ILM policy that will handle deletion of indexes that are out of a wanted timeframe

Besides that Elastic gives you API for managing such policies i.e [POST](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ilm-put-lifecycle.html) or [GET](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ilm-get-lifecycle.html) hence you can automate that within your application to avoid manual work and keep it all nice and consistent.

Indexes themselves usually easily managed by loggers, `Logback` for instance allow you to create dynamic indexes when you define its name in the configuration in the following way:

```
 <index>my-app-logs-%date{yyyy-MM-dd}</index
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, i use this to delete my expiration indexes.

**First,** you create a policy to describe when an index will be deleted

PUT http://localhost:9200/_ilm/policy/delete_log_after_2day <- Your policy name

```
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "min_age": "0ms",
        "actions": {
          "set_priority": {
            "priority": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "min_age": "2d", <-- Set your TTL here
        "actions": {
          "delete": {
            "delete_searchable_snapshot": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Next,** create a template to select which type of index will use this policy.

PUT http://localhost:9200/_index_template/delete_after2day_template

```
{
"index_patterns": [
    "test*" <-- Choose your index here
],
"template": {
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 1,
        "index.lifecycle.name": "delete_log_after_2day"
    }
}
}
```

Now, when you create a new index example: test001 it will be automatically deleted after 2 days.

**Note:**  for the old index, it will not assign to your new policy, so it won't be deleted except you assign it.

You can use this API to assign all old indexes to your policy

PUT http://localhost:9200/test*/_settings <--Your old index here, can use pattern

```
{
  "index": {
    "lifecycle": {
      "name": "delete_log_after_2day" <-- Your policy name
    }
  }
}
```

And then after your expiration date, all old indexes will be deleted completely.